# Modeling Without Dependent Variable

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, model

I’m trying to figure out this problem where I want to calculate the probability of a set of people underpaying a service.

The service needs to be paid as a percentage of people's income. The issue here is that in general people lie about their true income and there is no explicit dependent variable; which in a perfect world would be the label for people that have underpaid his services.

What I do have is information about the amount of money they have invested in cars, properties, companies...etc. What I’ve been doing is going for the anomalies such as:

- Expensives cars and very low income.
- Expensives properties and very low income.
- Etc.

What I need here is to establish a set of these parameters as the probability of certain person being underpayer.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. "What I need here is to establish a set of these parameters as the probability of certain person being underpayer." - this is very specific to your application. Further, since you don't have any observations of the 'underpaid' variable, approximating it in the described manner is close to guessing. Assuming one figures out a model for 'underpaid', is there a possibility from the business side to evaluate this in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be best to abandon this project - sometimes bad models are worse than no model at all. But if that is not an option, what I would do here is first model income as a function of the variables you do have. You can probably find data, at least roughly, that will help you do this. You might need to look for data on each major expense and its relation to income. Then you can try to combine these somehow - after all, if someone doesn't own a car, they can spend more on a house - and get some ballpark estimate of income. Then you can use this as the income variable and calculate "underpaying" which would be your dependent variable.

I'm not saying this is a great method. It's very messy. I would do a bunch of sensitivity analyses to see how much the results are affected by making different assumptions about income and its relation to expenses, but at least it is some kind of model.

Your current method looks very *ad hoc* and close to guesswork.